# GhostScript's file path in ImageMagick

Tags: xml, windows, macos, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am attempting to use ImageMagick to convert PDFs to PNGs on PC and OSX -- but I can't actually install GhostScript on any of the computers my software will be used on.

Is there a way to bundle GhostScript in with ImageMagick, and just redirect ImageMagick's path to that package, so I can use it without officially "installing" it on the user's computer?

[I found  this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14213), but I can't understand how one might change the delegates.xml file in ImageMagick to make it work correctly. I gather that I have to change some part of this line:

```
  <delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command=""@PSDelegate@" -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=epswrite "-sOutputFile=%o" -- "%i"" />
```

but I'm not sure what to do -- where to put the path in, or what the path should be based on --- ImageMagick's location, or something else? Any help would be super appreciated.

**UPDATE v1.2: I've attempted to change the delegate above to the following, with the executable in the command line:**

```
 <delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command="&quot;F:\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagick\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe&quot; -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=epswrite &quot;-sOutputFile=%o&quot; -- &quot;%i&quot;"/>
```

but when I run the program, I get the following error in the cmd prompt:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
```

(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

```
F:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>F:\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagick\convert.e
xe F:\ImageMagickTest\PDFs\Appointment.pdf F:\ImageMagickTest\ConvertedPDFs\Appo
intment.png
convert.exe: `%s' (%d) "F:/ImageMagickTest/ImageMagick/gs9.06/bin/gswin32c.exe"
-q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -d
EPSCrop -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -d
GraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=F:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/
magick-5996ZNQmVN7RFumY--0000001" "-fF:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/magick-5
996r7pmg8XgvrNB" "-fF:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/magick-5996yhTQgwoLswnn"
@ error/utility.c/SystemCommand/1890.
convert.exe: Postscript delegate failed `F:\ImageMagickTest\PDFs\Appointment.pdf
': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/679.
convert.exe: no images defined `F:\ImageMagickTest\ConvertedPDFs\Appointment.png
' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

To me, this would seem to indicate that it's not finding the file "Appointment.pdf". But it's there. What am I not grokking?

For fun, here is the full path of gs, as taken from windows explorer:

```
F:\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagick\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe
```

For even more fun, here is the c# script that is calling it, from within a Unity 3D application (I receive no errors):

```
    string currDir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string convertPath = currDir + @"\ImageMagick\convert.exe";
    string convertedDir = currDir + @"\ConvertedPDFs\";
    string pdfFolder = currDir + @"\PDFs\";
    string fileName = "Appointment";
    string argumentForImageMagick;


    argumentForImageMagick = pdfFolder + fileName + ".pdf" + " " + convertedDir + fileName + ".png";
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo {Arguments = argumentForImageMagick , FileName = convertPath};
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info).WaitForInputIdle();
```

Comment: Your update shows that you did not put the Ghostscript executable into the commandline, but only the directory where it is supposedly located: `.....\bin\`. On Windows, the executable you're looking for is named `gswin32c.exe` or `gswin64c.exe`.

Comment: Ok, cool, I've added the executable onto the end, but still no change. I've updated my original question with the new error -- mostly the same, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks again, by the way, for being such a great help. Couldn't be doing it without you.

Comment: Remove the two `@` characters which bracket your path. When you give the full path to the executable this is no longer a variable (as was the case with `@PSDeletage@`). It should read `... command="&quot;F:\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagick\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe&quot; ...` -- Also, you surely have checked that this indeed ***IS*** your Ghostscript executable?!

Comment: Hey, Kurt! Thanks for getting back to me. I'm positive that it's my executable file -- at least, that's where it shows itself in windows explorer -- the path appears to be F:\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagick\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe ... I've attempted to switch the delegate line around, but no luck. I've updated the error I'm receiving in the cmd line, as well.  It seems to be a similar error -- I wish I knew what it meant. I wish I knew more about xml! So you think it's definitely that it isn't finding the .exe?

Comment: By "switching the command line around", I mean that I've tried removing the @ symbols.

Comment: Your interpretation of the error message *'to indicate that it's not finding the file "Appointment.pdf"'* isn't correct. Instead it means, it didn't find the resulting image "Appointment.png" (which is no wonder, since the conversion didn't work -- for reasons not known yet...).

Comment: Catlard, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace the `""@PSDelegate" -q` part of that line by `"/usr/local/bin/gs -q` (or whatever path you're going to install the Ghostscript executables to).

Depending on your environment, you might need to add extra parameters to that command/line which tell `gs` (on Windows: `gswin32c.exe` or `gswin64c.exe`) where its libraries are to be found:
`-I/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.06/lib/`

---

**Update:**   Try to run this Ghostscript command directly in a cmd.exe window to see if it works (or which errors it spawns):

```
"F:/ImageMagickTest/ImageMagick/gs9.06/bin/gswin32c.exe" \
   -o F:/ImageMagickTest/PDFs/test.png                   \
   -dEPSCrop                                             \
   -dAlignToPixels=0                                     \
   -dGridFitTT=2                                         \
   -sDEVICE=pngalpha                                     \
   -dTextAlphaBits=4                                     \
   -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4                                 \
   -r72                                                  \
    F:/ImageMagickTest/PDFs/Appointment.pdf
```

Don't worry about my usage of forward slashes ('/') as directory separators -- Ghostscript on Windows can handle these just fine.

I hope your Ghostscript installation is a recent version (otherwise it won't understand the `-o` syntax for the output file).

If this command doesn't work, you should see some sort of error message in the window (because I skipped the `-q -dQUIET` params).

Probably Ghostscript doesn't find its libraries, because you may have copied the .exe file only, and not properly installed the full package.

Maybe you need to add `-I"F:/ImageMagickTest/ImageMagick/gs9.06/lib"` or something similar to the commandline (I don't know were your Ghostscript `/lib` directory really is located -- this is just a guess!):

```
"F:/ImageMagickTest/ImageMagick/gs9.06/bin/gswin32c.exe" \
   -o F:/ImageMagickTest/PDFs/test.png                   \
   -I"F:/ImageMagickTest/ImageMagick/gs9.06/lib"         \
   -dEPSCrop                                             \
   -dAlignToPixels=0                                     \
   -dGridFitTT=2                                         \
   -sDEVICE=pngalpha                                     \
   -dTextAlphaBits=4                                     \
   -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4                                 \
   -r72                                                  \
    F:/ImageMagickTest/PDFs/Appointment.pdf
```

You should only continue with the modifying the line in delegates.xml after you succeeded to run Ghostscript directly in the cmd.exe window.

Comment: Kurt! Thank you for the help. I'm trying to change the xml line as per your instructions...but I'm not sure if I'm determining the path correctly. I've updated the question to reflect it...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this trying to use ImageMagick and GhostScript on a computer without administration rights (using portable versions of both). Got the error messing trying to manually set the path to GhostScript within the delegates.xml, trying to batch covert PDF files to TIFF.

The **solution** i found was to replace all the instances of `"@PSDelegate"` with the full path, like: `&quot;C:\<path_to_exec>\gswin32c.exe&quot;` in the delegates.xml file, and not only the PDF specific line. It worked fine after this.

This probably since GhostScript is used for other formats as well, and is perhaps dependent on other `"@PSDelegate"` instances within the delegates.xml file when converting a PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a problem on Windows 10.

I tried different options, but ImageMagick always tried using gs.exe. So I did something which I thought wouldn't work and basically renamed my **gswin64c.exe** file to **gc.exe**.

And after that it just worked. The only thing I needed was to add the path to my environment variables where the exe was located, which in my case was: `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the `Postscript delegate failed` message when running ImageMagick for PDF reading.  Problem was caused by ImageMagick reading one of the following registry entries (under SOFTAWRE) to get path to gs executable on Windows.

- GPL Ghostscript
- GNU Ghostscript
- AFPL Ghostscript
- Aladdin Ghostscript

Problem was this pointed to a very old version of Ghost script, installed on user's machine, and failed to convert PDF to image.

Solution was to uninstall offending ancient package from machine, or update the delegates.xml file to explicitly point to the shipped gs executable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and none of the answers helped. It turned out that there was a 32 bit version of ImageMagick and a 64 bit version of GhostScript installed which didn't play nicely. So we removed the 64 bit GhostScript and installed a 32 bit version instead and it worked fine after undating the paths in the delegates.xml